# Formulas for pointwise and uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I am looking at formulas for testing pointwise versus uniform convergence from Kenneth Ross' text, which are respectively:
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n (x) = f(x), \  \text{for all } x \in S$$
and
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} [\sup \{|f(x) - f_n(x)|: x \in S\}] = 0.$$

In all the examples and exercises in the text, however, the $f(x)$'s are in reality given as constants.

Here is my question: Why doesn't the text just use the constant notation $c$ directly instead of using $f(x)$? Is it because in the eye of $f_n(x)$, that $f(x)$ is seen as a constant? What does $f(x)$ really mean? The typical $f_n(x)$ given in the exercises is $f_n(x) = x^n / (n + x^n)$ in intervals of either $[0, 1]$ or $[0, \infty)$

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Constants are often used as simple examples but f does not need to be one. When checking for uniform convegrence f(x) is usually defined as $f(x) :=lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response!

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can put
$$g_n(x)=f_n(x)-f(x)$$
and reduce to the case
$$g(x)=0$$
So your book treats the case $f(x)=c$ for the sake of simplicity knowing that it is as interesting as the general case

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response.